# Not Able to Set Height Of Div Dynamically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://www.bootply.com/WEc8WJrcIj) and let me know why I am not able to set the height of `.box` dynamically?

```
$(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){ // On load
        $('.box').css({'height':(($(window).height()))+'px'});
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){ // On resize
        $('.box').css({'height':(($(window).height()))+'px'});
    });
});

<section>
<div class="col-md-12" id="box-1">Height has been set!</div>
</section>
<section>
<div class="col-md-12" id="box-2">Height has been set!</div>
</section>
<section>
<div class="col-md-12" id="box-3">Height has been set!</div>
</section>
<section>
<div class="col-md-12" id="box-4">Height has been set!</div>
</section>
<section>
<div class="col-md-12" id="box-5">Height has been set!</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Link doesn't work for me; maybe jsFiddle would be better...?

Comment: There are no elements with the class `.box` in your example and the link you provided doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are using the wrong selector. You need to query for your class which is named "col-md-12".

Then, you are using the `window.load()` event which was removed from JQuery in 3.0 (see [here](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)). You can either use `$(document).ready(function() {})` or `$(window).on("load",function(){})`

Your code should look like this:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){ // On load
        $('.col-md-12').css({'height':(($(window).height()))+'px'});
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){ // On resize
        $('.col-md-12').css({'height':(($(window).height()))+'px'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to a class that's not present.
Instead of $(".box"), use $("[id^='box-']") - you're not looking for the ones with "box" class but the ones with *an id property starting with the string 'box-'*.

(Alternatively, you could add a "box" class to each element you want to size and leave the original jQuery selector; maybe it's a better approach, it depends on the logic of the rest of your site. You decide.)

1. $("[id^='box-']")
2. $(".box") and divs like class="col-md-12 box"